# Array assignment Snake

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Working in a business environment, I don't really get to code or use the good old console anymore. My work is repetitive and thus not really challenging.

I decided to challenge myself by writing a snake game in a C# console; and boy did it make my brain work. I never have to think this hard on a day-to-day basis, but I felt like my programming skills weren't getting any better.

I have a problem though. The basic approach I took was to create a snake class and a food class. The snake class uses an array to store all coordinates and then a drawing class decides what coords to draw on-screen.

The problem is that as you move the snake, the array fills up (maxsize is 250 for performance), so when I reach the end of the array I want to copy the last few coords to a temp array, flush the original array and copy the temp coords back to the main array.

The problem I have is copying x coords back to the original array. I decided to do it manually to test but this solution always makes my poor snake leave behind one of its segments on the screen when it shouldn't be there.

How would I go about doing this programmatically?

```
spoints[4, 0] = stemp[249, 0];
spoints[4, 1] = stemp[249, 1];
spoints[4, 2] = stemp[249, 2];

spoints[3, 0] = stemp[248, 0];
spoints[3, 1] = stemp[248, 1];
spoints[3, 2] = stemp[248, 2];

spoints[2, 0] = stemp[247, 0];
spoints[2, 1] = stemp[247, 1];
spoints[2, 2] = stemp[247, 2];

spoints[1, 0] = stemp[246, 0];
spoints[1, 1] = stemp[246, 1];
spoints[1, 2] = stemp[246, 2];

spoints[0, 0] = stemp[245, 0];
spoints[0, 1] = stemp[245, 1];
spoints[0, 2] = stemp[245, 2];
```

I really don't mind posting the whole game here if someone really wants to dig into the code.

Comment: You're making your life harder by using arrays instead of typed collections/dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an array for 'general points' not drawing points, create another class called something like `SnakePart` so your `Snake` class has manageable parts.

You could also create a custom array class so in each part of the grid you would only have a value `hasSnakePart` and manipulate that.

Comment: Hyp : you are making my brain hurt, the last time i programmed like this was 7 years ago in highschool, so i wanted it to be VERY basic lol

Comment: Ah but that's the fun part isn't it! Make your brain work, make it interesting!

Comment: True, but baby steps :) next is to make an AI snake so the game is interesting and then to make the snakes shoot venom  to slow the other snake down etc

Comment: YES! And then you can add 'snake shouts' - 'fus-ro-dah' all the way... hmmm snakes have no knees.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like an array is the wrong data type for your purposes. Consider using a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead, since it allows for more flexibility when moving entries around.

Comment: Thanks! I will use a list, but for the time being i just want to know how to do that programmatically :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about as you add a new coordinate to the 'front' of the array, removing the one at the 'back' as you go.  So basically, a sort of FIFO type collection?!  You could use a Queue in C#.  Have a look at this article and see if it helps any?!  http://www.dotnetperls.com/queue.

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: CHris, im plotting all points but my drawing class is drawing all but the last point in every iteration.I didnt go this route because then the snake will have no tail and only be 1 character moving on the screen lol - edit - sorry i see your logic now, i would just have to have a var that keeps track of the amount of segments the snake has.